# What are the legal uses of the data from livingwage.mit.edu?

Tags: licensing, web-crawling, legal

What are the legal uses of [this data](http://livingwage.mit.edu/)?

For example, could I design a non-for-profit service using this data, a for-profit application that I sell subscriptions to, or a spreadsheet that I use myself that pulls data from this website?

If this isn't the correct platform, let me know and I'll ask it somewhere more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

This site helps to calculate the cost of living in different parts of the United States.  There's a caveat about the fidelity and comprehensiveness of the data ("Consider the results a minimum cost threshold that serves as a benchmark, but only that.").

For licensing, the site references that it is part of the [Living Wage Project](http://povertyinamerica.mit.edu/projects/living_wage/). However, in looking through all those sites, there are no references to data use and licensing.

To verify the licensing, you can contact the [author](http://mailto:amyglas@mit.edu) of the page or the [project team](http://povertyinamerica.mit.edu/contact/). (I'm in contact now with the author to clarify the data use rules.)

Comment: I've been looking into how the site calculates it and I'm relatively comfortable with its methods for my purposes - namely to compare COL info across the US. So really as long as it is a somewhat consisted threshold, even if that threshold is low it should be okay. Thanks for checking with them, I tried, requested they think about an API in the future and then got very confusing responses.